# Converting a transaction log into a data frame for cohort analysis

Tags: r, refactoring

EDIT: Now made reproducible by using a publicly available dataset.

I would like to take a transaction log `e_log`, with the following schema:

```
require(BTYD)
e_log <- dc.ReadLines(system.file("data/cdnowElog.csv", package="BTYD"),2,3,5)
e_log[,"date"] <- as.Date(e_log[,"date"], "%Y%m%d")
e_log$cust<-as.integer(e_log$cust)

head(e_log)
     cust    date  sales
1    1  1997-01-01 29.33
2    1  1997-01-18 29.73
3    1  1997-08-02 14.96
4    1  1997-12-12 26.48
5    2  1997-01-01 63.34
6    2  1997-01-13 11.77
```

Where each instance is a transaction and `cust` is the customer id, `date` is the transaction date and `sales` is the sales amount, and transform it  into the following schema (note that the columns are not ordered):

```
cust trans_date sales      birth date_diff
1    1 1997-01-01 29.33 1997-01-01    0 days
2    1 1997-01-16  0.00 1997-01-01   15 days
3    1 1997-08-27  0.00 1997-01-01  238 days
4    1 1997-09-11  0.00 1997-01-01  253 days
5    1 1998-04-23  0.00 1997-01-01  477 days
6    1 1997-08-17  0.00 1997-01-01  228 days
```

Where `cust` is the customer id, `trans_date` is the transaction date in year/month/day, `sales` is the sum of sales for a given `trans_date` and `cust`, `birth` is the date of acquisition, and `date_diff` is the number of days elapsed from when the customer was acquired to the `trans_date`. In this schema, the primary key is `cust` and `date_diff`. There should be a row for every customer, for every day elapsed since the customer was acquired up until the maximum date in the dataset (i.e. the final observation time), regardless of whether there was a sale on a given day. The goal is to see sales as a function of days elapsed from acquisition.

I have created a function that converts a transaction log to the above schema, but its slow, crude, and inefficient (not to be too hard on my self):

```
require(BTYD)
cohort_spend.df<-function(trans_log){ 

###create a customer by time spend matrix 
spend<-dc.CreateSpendCBT(trans_log)

###coerce to data.frame
sdf<-data.frame(spend)

###order elog by date, create birth index
e_ord<-trans_log[,1:2][with(trans_log[,1:2],order(date)),]
birth<-by(e_ord,e_ord$cust,head,n=1)
birthd<-do.call("rbind",as.list(birth))

colnames(birthd)<-c("cust","birth")

###merge birth dates to customer spend data frame
sdfm<-merge(sdf,birthd,by="cust")

###difference transaction date and birth date to get days elapsed 
###from acquisition
sdfm$date<-as.Date(sdfm$date)
sdfm$diff<-sdfm$date-sdfm$birth
sdfm2<-sdfm[sdfm$diff>=0,]
colnames(sdfm2)<-c("cust","trans_date","sales","birth","date_diff")
return(sdfm2)}



desired_schema<-cohort_spend.df(trans_log=e_log)

head(desired_schema)
cust trans_date sales      birth date_diff
1    1 1997-01-01 29.33 1997-01-01    0 days
2    1 1997-01-16  0.00 1997-01-01   15 days
3    1 1997-08-27  0.00 1997-01-01  238 days
4    1 1997-09-11  0.00 1997-01-01  253 days
5    1 1998-04-23  0.00 1997-01-01  477 days
6    1 1997-08-17  0.00 1997-01-01  228 days

system.time(cohort_spend.df(trans_log=e_log))
   user  system elapsed 
  46.777   0.967  47.768
```

I've included the function so that you can reproduce my results. Again, the output is correct, I'm simply looking to refactor; If you can think of a cleaner way to get the desired result, please share.

NOTE: the desired schema should be derived entirely from the transaction log, with no need for external data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my solution using data.table, building on Troy's solution:

```
   require(BTYD)
   require(data.table)
   cohort_spend.dft<-function(e_log){
   e_log<-dc.MergeTransactionsOnSameDate(e_log) ##merge same day transactions
   DT<-data.table(e_log,key=c("date","cust"))         # turn the frame into a table
   births<-DT[,list(birth=min(date)),by="cust"]       # list births
   grid<-CJ(date=as.Date(min(DT[,date]):max(DT[,date]),origin="1970-01-01"),cust=unique(DT[,cust]))   # make the grid of all combinations
   grid<-merge(DT,grid,all.y=T)  # merge in the data from the log
   grid[is.na(sales),sales:=0]                    # set NA sales value to 0
   grid<-merge(grid,births,by="cust")     # merge in the birth
   grid[,date_diff:=date-birth][date_diff>=0] 
   } 

 system.time(cohort_spend.dft(e_log=e_log))

 user  system elapsed 
 1.783   0.532   2.413
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDITED TO INCLUDE ZERO VALUES**

```
require(data.table)

DT<-data.table(e_log,key=c("date","cust"))         # turn the frame into a table
births<-DT[,list(birth=min(date)),by="cust"]       # list births
grid<-CJ(date=as.Date(min(DT[,date]):max(DT[,date]),origin="1970-01-01"),cust=unique(DT[,cust]))                       # make the grid of all combinations
grid<-merge(DT,grid,all.y=T)                   # merge in the data from the log
grid<-merge(grid,births,all.x=T,by="cust")     # merge in the birth
grid[is.na(sales),sales:=0]                    # set NA sales value to 0
grid[,date_diff:=paste(date_diff=date-birth," Days")]  # add the date_diff field
setkey(grid,cust,date)                                 # set the key
grid[,list(sales=sum(sales),birth,date_diff),by=c("cust","date")]  # output

cust       date sales      birth date_diff
1:    1 1997-01-01 29.33 1997-01-01   0  Days
2:    1 1997-01-02  0.00 1997-01-01   1  Days
3:    1 1997-01-03  0.00 1997-01-01   2  Days
4:    1 1997-01-04  0.00 1997-01-01   3  Days
5:    1 1997-01-05  0.00 1997-01-01   4  Days
---                                           
1287141: 2357 1998-06-26  0.00 1997-03-25 458  Days
1287142: 2357 1998-06-27  0.00 1997-03-25 459  Days
1287143: 2357 1998-06-28  0.00 1997-03-25 460  Days
1287144: 2357 1998-06-29  0.00 1997-03-25 461  Days
1287145: 2357 1998-06-30  0.00 1997-03-25 462  Days
```

Actually, to filter out the date prior to each entry's birth:

```
grid[,list(sales=sum(sales),birth,date_diff),by=c("cust","date")][date>=birth]


   cust       date sales      birth date_diff
1:    1 1997-01-01 29.33 1997-01-01   0  Days
2:    1 1997-01-02  0.00 1997-01-01   1  Days
3:    1 1997-01-03  0.00 1997-01-01   2  Days
4:    1 1997-01-04  0.00 1997-01-01   3  Days
5:    1 1997-01-05  0.00 1997-01-01   4  Days
---                                           
1185816: 2357 1998-06-26  0.00 1997-03-25 458  Days
1185817: 2357 1998-06-27  0.00 1997-03-25 459  Days
1185818: 2357 1998-06-28  0.00 1997-03-25 460  Days
1185819: 2357 1998-06-29  0.00 1997-03-25 461  Days
1185820: 2357 1998-06-30  0.00 1997-03-25 462  Days
```

Comment: The data for birth should be derived from the transaction log. If you look at my function, I'm deriving the birth for each customer by finding the date of the first transaction for each customer. Again, my function gives the correct output and only requires a transaction log as an argument; I'm simply looking to refactor.

Comment: OK updated to used earlier date per client for birth_day

Comment: and I guess I should have called it sdf, not df

Comment: I get an error when I try your solution. Can you post the full solution? I've updated my post with a publicly available dataset so that there's no ambiguity

Comment: OK that's done - it seems to want presummarization on the date, and for some reason it lost the format

Comment: I have also added a data.table example - less intuitive, but I am not sure why dplyr is messing up the date format

Comment: You are leaving out all instances where sales = 0. This is important because 0 is a value, and affects the ability to aggregate the resulting data.frame (say, find the mean of sales at a given date_diff). Otherwise, your solution works. Sorry if my original explanation was unclear, I updated it some 30 mins ago.

Comment: Also, I recognize the result is quite large (45.3Mb)

Comment: OK I see - one question - is there a record for every date min to max, or only for every date where any customer has a transaction?

Comment: there is a record for every date min to max, with the only condition being that date_diff>=0

Comment: I checked the sum the sales vector from your result, and it doesn't equal the sum of the sales vector in the original transaction log, which means something's wrong (the sum of sales should be the same, via the rule of associativity)